# Presto - Turn 2 arrays into separate mapped entities using each index of the array

Tags: sql, presto

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do this in presto. After querying I have two aggregated arrays a and b. I'd like to figure out how to turn each index of the array into a map with static labels for each value in a and b.

See below for example. I've toyed around all the various array map functions in the Presto documentation but cannot seem to figure it out. Any thoughts?

Note: The length of a and b will always be the same as each other, but can vary between lengths of 1 through 10

Input

```
select
array_agg('a','b','c') as a,
array_agg(1,2,3) as b
from etc...
```

which turns into

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| ['a','b','c'] | [1,2,3] |

Then, after some transformation...

Desired Output:

```
{
    'static_label_char' -> 'a',
    'static_label_num' -> 1
},
{
    'static_label_char' -> 'b',
    'static_label_num' -> 2
},
{
    'static_label_char' -> 'c',
    'static_label_num' -> 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that you can create a map containing different types as values, but you can zip your arrays and transform the result to rows with named fields:

```sql
SELECT transform(
  zip(a, b),
  r -> cast(r AS ROW(static_label_char CHAR, static_label_num SMALLINT)))
FROM 
    (SELECT ARRAY['a','b','c'] AS a, ARRAY[1,2,3] AS b)
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [{static_label_char=a, static_label_num=1}, {static_label_char=b, static_label_num=2}, {static_label_char=c, static_label_num=3}] |

And then you can use dot notation to access the named field. For example with `unnest`:

```sql
SELECT r.static_label_char, r.static_label_num
FROM 
    (SELECT transform( zip(a, b),
         r -> cast(r AS ROW(static_label_char CHAR, static_label_num SMALLINT))) AS rows
    FROM 
        (SELECT ARRAY['a','b','c'] AS a, ARRAY[1,2,3] AS b) )
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(rows) AS t (r);
```

Output:

| static_label_char | static_label_num |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

Comment: Hmm okay I will play around with it and see what I can find. thank you! will update if I find an answer